# The sum of the cubes of two different prime numbers is 5256.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Is an simple way to solve the problem?

> The sum of the cubes of two different prime numbers is 5256. What are the two primes?

Here is what I did: assume the two numbers are $x$ and $y$, then I have $x^3+y^3=5256$. I can try x and y, but I don't think it is the most effective method. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, try the biggest one first ($17$), since that will tell you immediately that $2, 3, 5$ are too small anyways. Then you're down to four. But the answer below is more constructive, so go for that.

Comment: Curiously enough, the only solution to the equation $x^3 + y^3 = 5256$ to use negative numbers involves two composite even numbers, e.g., $x = -14$.

Answer (score 3):

We might as well take $x \ge y$.  Then $18 \gt \sqrt[3]{5256} \gt 17$, so $x$ cannot be greater than $17$.  $x$ has to be at least $\sqrt[3]{5256/2} \gt 13$ so we know $x=17$ as it is the only prime in the range.  Now $y=\sqrt[3]{5256-17^3}=7$ and we are done without checking any cases.

Comment: (+1) this was my idea as well, but even more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest way is notice that
$$
18^3 = 5832 > 5256,
$$
So if $x^3 + y^3 = 5256$, then $x$ and $y$ are between $1$ and $17$.
But you also know they are prime, so you have that
$$
x, y \in \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17\}.
$$
We can then cube them to get
$$
x^3, y^3 \in \{8, 27, 125, 343, 1331, 2197, 4913\}. \tag{1}
$$
Now we subtract each element from $5256$:
$$
5256 - x^3, 5256 - y^3 \in \{5248, 5229, 5131, 4913, 3925, 3059, 343\}. \tag{2}
$$
Since $x^3 = 5256 - y^3$, $x^3$ is in BOTH the set (1) and the set (2).
The intersection of these two sets is $\{343, 4913\} = \{7^3, 17^3\}$.
So
$x = 7$ or $x = 17$, and correspondingly, $y = 17$ or $y = 7$, respectively.